# hidden class bootstrap doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="header">
            <a href="#" class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1 logo"></a>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-1 nav hidden-sm-down "></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.header{
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("san_fran.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

.top-header{
    width: 100%;
}
.logo{
    background: url("logo-cinetik.png") center center no-repeat;
    height: 130px;
    min-width: 400px;
}

.nav{
    background-color: $test-color;
    height: 100px;
}
```

the div tag has the hidden-sm-down class. It should be hidden when my window is less than a certain point isn't it ?

Here is the result

[image]

The red div should be hidden!
How can i do this ?

Comment: I want my div to appear when it's up from sm device size

Comment: which version of bootstrap u r using??

Comment: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: hidden-sm-down is a class of bootstarp 4, in bootstrap 3 isn´t used 'down' suffix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the classes devices based.

**Extra small devices**
Phones (<768px) `(Class names : .visible-xs-block, hidden-xs)`

**Small devices**
Tablets (≥768px) `(Class names : .visible-sm-block, hidden-sm)`

**Medium devices**
Desktops (≥992px) `(Class names : .visible-md-block, hidden-md)`

**Large devices**
Desktops (≥1200px) `(Class names : .visible-lg-block, hidden-lg)`

Refer this link for more http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: i read something for the v4 .. http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/